# How can I assign a byte array to an enum variable and print it?

Tags: java, arrays, enums, byte, assign

I want to assign an array of bytes value to an `enum` variable. I'm able to assign one byte to a variable but unable to assign a whole byte array. How can I do that? (I hope my question is not absurd.)

```
public enum abc
{
       a (new byte[] {0x11,0x22},
       b ((byte)0x17);
       byte value;
       byte[] val=new byte[2];
       private abc(byte[] val)
       {
            this.val=val;
       }
       private abc(byte value)
       {
            this.value=value;
       }
 }
```

now if i want to print abc.a...it is showing me 0 instead of 11 22.And i want to print the whole sequence as 11 22 17 by storing all values in an array.How can i do it?(is my question clear now?)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you please show the code for what you mean by “assign one byte to a[n enum] variable”.  Because I'm not quite sure what you mean with this.  Maybe if we can see that code we will understand better what you want to do.

Comment: @Abinaya: what do you mean by 'print' - is it about calling the enums' `toString` method?

Comment: if you called the second constructor then yes the array would be empty as you didn't assign value to it. b.value == 17, and b.val[0] == b.val[1]==0, in case of a => a.value ==0, a.val[0]==11, a.val[1]==12

Comment: @TacB0sS : so what is the solution to it?

Comment: You want all values (passed to *different* invocations of the constructor) into a *single* array?  It *could* be done with a `static` variable but down that path lies madness.  Is this for a particular problem you are trying to model?  If so, please tell us.  I'm sure we'll find a cleaner solution.  This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: actually i am creating a complete Frame packet used in a protocol..and some fields are constant and hence i made them enum type and trying to consolidate into one frame.

Comment: So just create a constructor that excepts both values... abc(byte[] array, byte value)

Comment: @TacB0sS : can u illustrate this with an example?

Comment: I took it a step further and now you have two examples, in one constructor... you can provide multiple parameters, you can combine arrays, or simply add a value to the array, play with it... it does work I use this sort of technic all the time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public enum CustomEnumConstructor {
    Fibonacci(new int[]{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21}, new int[]{34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610}, 987),
    SternBrocot(new int[]{1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3}), ;

    private final int[] array;

    private CustomEnumConstructor(int[] array1, int[] array2, int value) {
        int[] array12 = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
        System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array12, 0, array1.length);
        System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array12, array1.length, array2.length);

        array = new int[array12.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(array12, 0, array, 0, array12.length);
        array[array12.length] = value;
    }

    private CustomEnumConstructor(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public int[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this might be what the OP wants but honestly, your identifiers are very disturbing.  I had to read your code like three times until I understood what it means.

Comment: yes...but i am still getting 0 as their values instead of those arrays {1,2,3,4}

Comment: @5gon12eder The identifiers are very disturbing?

Comment: @TacB0sS It's better since you've renamed `density` to `array` but why did you name it `CustomEnumConstructor`?  It's not a “constructor”, it's an `enum` type.  Oh, and make `array` `final`.

Comment: @5gon12eder **CustomEnumConstructor** is for the example of an enum with a custom constructor... I thought it would make sense :)

Comment: Well, it didn't make that much sense to me but I'll +1 you now because it's the same answer – albeit with different names ;) – that I would have given.